# how to use custom java rule on sonar?

Tags: java, xpath, plugins, sonarqube, rule

i'm using sonar for a lot of customer projects, many customer need to have custom rules, I have always created rules for java with xpath, but now xpath are removed for java classes.

I'm using sonarQube ver. 4.5.1 and java plugin Ver. 2.9.1

In the documentation of sonar : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Custom+Rules+for+Java

I see that custom rules for java requires at least version 3.1 for plugin java, and changes made between ver. 3.0 and 3.1, that need to rewrite some classes.

I need to know how I can use the custom rule for java code with my actual configuration, and if I create custom rule now, will I rewrite some class of custom rule for any upgrade of java plugin??

Comment: For many many many reasons (see the release notes of the java plugin) you would really be better off using a recent version of the java plugin (ie 3.10 or upper)

Comment: yes i know, but i have 150 project, and 1100 user, it's a shared platform, i can't upgrade plugin for any update, because for each upgrade i made it's a big site, i need to make a lot of test of no regression, and to test it in dev platform and pre-prod and after installing in prod, as you can see each upgrade take more thn 3 month of testing etc. i need solution thanks for your response

Comment: Matter of opinion here, but I don't think those are good reasons not to upgrade : upgrading will get you less bugs, more rules and will allow you to develop custom rules faster. We test non regression on our side. I think taking the shortcut to develop custom rules for an outdated plugin will only lead you to a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found how to generate a custom java rule plugin,

I created a project template that he can generate the custom java rule

i posted the project on git, everyone can use it, the link of the project is : 
https://github.com/cecef/sonar-CustomRule-plugin

Regards,
Youssef

Comment: Can I ask you to review [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085), please?

Answer (score 2):

If you write custom rules for java plugin  version 2.9.1, yes you will encounter breaking changes when upgrading to a more recent version of the plugin in this case (which I can't recommend you enough).

We (java plugin developers) try to keep breaking changes of the API to a minimum but since version 2.9.1 it has happen.

Looking at the example in the doc for 3.1 might get you started to write custom rules but things will be different and you will have to figure things out.

Comment: Thank you very much, ok i see, but after the version 3.1 sonar will make change of the way of coding custom rule on a newest version or that will be stable ?

Comment: We are currently at version 3.10 of the plugin. And (as far as I remember) it did not change that much. We try to keep things as stable as possible and avoid breaking changes. But in order to go forward with the API we may have to do it from time to time.

Comment: For many many many reason we can't upgrade the java plugin now because :
1 - first that need upgrade of sonarQube to 4.5.6+
2 - we just made an update of sonarQube last month, and it take long time.
3 - we have shared Platforme between JAVA and .NET and the latest version that are compatible between those is 4.5.1 
4- we can't make an upgrade of both platforme Java and .net just for this functionnality

so if you have a work arround or a solution to make the xpath rules working it will be helpfull for us.
If there is no work around then we will have to upgrade but it should be our last option

Comment: XPath is not supported anymore by the Java Plugin, and it won't come back. There is consequently no workaround. Rules will have to be rewritten. Any rule you are writing now, based on XPath, will have to be migrated too.

Comment: Ok thank you Michael but as said by benzonico before  "we test non regression on our side" 
how can you explain that xpath rules was worked on version 4.0 but not working with the version 4.5.1 ??
The problem is that i've discovered this dysfunctionality after the upgrade because it wasn't mentioned nowhere...that xpath don't work with java plugin from 2.9.1

Comment: I need to know if i have a way to create a custom java rule with my actual version 2.9.1?  do you have a wiki for that, i didin't find anything. thank you in advance

Comment: Look at my answer again : "Looking at the example in the doc for 3.1 might get you started to write custom rules (for 2.9.1) but things will be different and you will have to figure things out."

Comment: ok thank you benzonico for your time and response, i tried to create custom rule for java plugin 2.9.1 and i followed the step like described in the docs sonar for ver 3.1 but i don't find my rule in sonar, can you help me to create my first custom java rule because i always used xpath rule and now i'm blocked this is my custom rule :

If there is a `@Stateless ` or  `@Stateful ` annotation on a class, there should be a  `@Interceptors ` annotation. If it's not the case, it should be a Critical issue.